# How to change table row background color on hover or mouseover in Material ui datatable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mousehover, mui-datatable

Very very new to React and Material-UI.

I'm trying to change the color of the table rows when the pointer / mouse is moved over the rows , i.e. on hover.

I have tried 'solutions' from other posts but no success.
(e.g. Root and cell and tableRow)

The xx.js

```
export const xxTheme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: 'xxText',
        fontSize: 11,
    },

    tableRow: {
       "&$hover:hover": { backgroundColor: "blue"  }
    },

    tableCell: {
        "$hover:hover &": { color: "pink"
    }
},
hover: {},

overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
        root:{
            color: xxColors.grey2,
            '& .MuiCheckbox': { color: xxColors.grey2, },
            "&$hover:hover" : { backgroundColor: "blue" }
        },
        head: {...}

        tableRow: { "&$hover:hover": { backgroundColor: "cyan" }
        },
    },
```

In the xxTableBody.js

```
import {Table, TableContainer} from "@material-ui/core";
import {Checkbox, TableBody, TableCell, TableRow} from "@material-ui/core";
import {xxColors} from "../styles/xx";

<TableRow
    key={step.workStepId}
    ref={dragProvided.innerRef}
    selected={isItemSelected}
    aria-checked={isItemSelected}
    {...dragProvided.draggableProps}

    classes={{'hover':{color:'#7EA55FF'}}}
    style={{
          ...dragProvided.draggableProps.style,
          background: snapshot.isDragging   ? xxColors.blue1 : "none",
          }}
    >
   <TableCell key={'drag'} align={'left'}>
       <div {...dragProvided.dragHandleProps}>
           <ReorderIcon/>
       </div>
   </TableCell>
```

What needs doing/fixing?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the jss conditional 'snapshot.isDragging'  thru to setting background = none, and using std css, resolved that problem.